# Keyboard shortcuts in Spyder: Is the differentiation between "Enter" and "Return" voluntary?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, spyder

In the keyboard shortcuts in Spyder IDE, the keys "Enter" and "Return" differ, with "Enter" being the one on the number block, and "Return" the other one. Is this voluntary, i.e. is there a clear advantage to this distinction?

I am asking because I falsely thought certain keyboard shortcuts do not work on my installation. E.g., the default to run a cell in version 5.4.3 on Windows is "Ctrl"+"Return", meaning pressing "Ctrl" together with the "Enter" key on number block does nothing.

It is possible to change the keyboard shortcuts individually to use either "Enter" or "Return", but not both.